# Is a network flow equivalent to a walk?

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Consider a directed graph where each edge has infinite capacity. 
Now consider a directed walk on this graph from arbirtary node *s* to arbitrary node *t* with $s \neq t$.

**Definition** (Directed walk): *A walk is a sequence of not necessarily distinct edges directed in the same direction which joins a sequence of
vertices. It differs from a path because a walk can contain cycles.*

With this walk we can build an *s,t*-flow of size 1 where the following condition holds: the flow on every edge *e* is equal to how manny times *e* appears in the walk.

I'm pretty sure the flow we just built is valid because if the walk passes *i* times from node *v* with $v \notin$ {$s,t$} then node *v* sees a flow of size *i* entering and a flow of size *i* leaving. It's not a formal proof but I think I can write one down.

What I'm not so sure about is if we can do exactly the reverse: build a directed walk between nodes *s* and *t* for every *s,t*-flow of size 1 such that the same condition as above holds.

My question is: is it possible to build a walk for every flow, and if yes how would I go about prooving it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sum of a flow of $1$ along a directed path from $s$ to $t$ and a flow of $1$ along a directed cycle that does not share any nodes with the path.

Comment: Yes verry smart, what if we consider only flows that dont have these "detached" flow cycles?

Comment: According to the flow decomposition theorem, that is all that can go wrong.